# How to deploy two laravel applications with docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, devops, cicd

When you deploy the laravel application using docker in production you need at least two containers **Nginx**, **PHP** and the source code should be in both containers, if you deploy another laravel application on the same (port, server) you have to put the source code of the second application in the **Nginx** container too which makes both applications depend on each other and cause problems for CI/CD.

Is there a way to deploy both applications independently using docker on the same (port, server) but on different domains?

Comment: I think you can use the nginx reverse proxy to achieve that

https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Docker-Nginx-reverse-proxy-setup-example